# Using generics in F# to create an EnumArray type

Tags: generics, f#, enums, compiler-errors

I've created an F# class to represent an array that allocates one element for each value of a specific enum. I'm using an explicit constructor that creates a dictionary from enum values to array indices, and an Item property so that you can write expressions like:

```
let my_array = new EnumArray<EnumType, int>
my_array.[EnumType.enum_value] <- 5
```

However, I'm getting the following obscure compilation error at the line marked with '// FS0670' below.

```
error FS0670: This code is not sufficiently generic.
The type variable  ^e when  ^e : enum<int> and  ^e : equality
and  ^e : (static member op_Explicit :  ^e -> int)
could not be generalized because it would escape its scope.
```

I'm at a loss - can anyone explain this error?

```
type EnumArray< 'e, 'v when 'e : enum<int>  //'
                       and 'e : equality
                       and 'e : (static member op_Explicit :  'e -> int) > =
    val enum_to_int : Dictionary<'e, int>  //'
    val a : 'v array  //'

    new() as this =
        { 
            enum_to_int = new Dictionary<'e, int>()  //'
            a = Array.zeroCreate (Enum.GetValues(typeof<'e>).Length)  //'
        }
        then
            for (e : obj) in Enum.GetValues(typeof<'e>) do  //'
                this.enum_to_int.Add(e :?> 'e, int(e :?> 'e))

    member this.Item
        with get (idx : 'e) : 'v = this.a.[this.enum_to_int.[idx]]  // FS0670
        and set (idx : 'e) (c : 'v) = this.a.[this.enum_to_int.[idx]] <- c
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here you go:

```
open System
open System.Collections.Generic 

type EnumArray<'e, 'v when 'e : enum<int> and 'e : equality>() = 
    let dict = new Dictionary<'e, int>()    //'
    let values = Enum.GetValues(typeof<'e>) //'
    let a = Array.zeroCreate values.Length
    do
        for (o : obj) in values do 
            let e = o :?> 'e   //'
            dict.Add(e, LanguagePrimitives.EnumToValue(e)) 
    member this.Item 
        with get idx  = a.[dict.[idx]]
        and set idx c = a.[dict.[idx]] <- c

let d = new EnumArray<StringSplitOptions, string>()
d.[StringSplitOptions.None] <- "foo"
d.[StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries] <- "bar"
```

A key aspect is [LanguagePrimitives.EnumToValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353645.aspx), which removes the need for the static member constraints.  (Use of static member constraints is bad enough, but when things fail with them, the compiler diagnostics are even worse.)